# Сломалась подсветка и подсказки VSCode

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

После чего, сам не знаю, сломалось подкрашивание некоторого кода, а также авто-подсказки не срабатывают (Методы как раз тех библиотек которые не закрашены)
Сам код при этом работает.

[image: Скрин1]

[image: Скрин2]

Comment: Перезагрузка помогает?

Comment: @DaLadno нет, перезапуск, как и перезагрузка компьютера не помогает, к сожалению

Comment: @DaLadno Установлен, ms-python.vscode-pylance
Еще буквально пару дней назад всё подсвечивалось, всё было хорошо, а потом в один момент всё сломалось. Будто какая-то частичка VSCode перестала работать.
Буду пробовать переустановить с 0 VSCode. Надеюсь поможет.
Просто хотел разобраться без переустановки, но видимо это единственный вариант (Надеюсь хотя бы он поможет)

Comment: Переустановка не помогла.
Если отключаю расширение python, то все библиотеки становятся белыми. 
Когда снова включаю, библиотеки красятся только частично как на скринах выше.
Переустановка расширения также не помогла.
Версия питон актуальная, с версией в VSCode справа внизу, совпадает.
Я в замешательстве, вообще не знаю что делать